# SVG Mask re-use

Tags: svg

I'm creating some SVG with D3.JS. I have a group of SVG elements that I repeat for each of the items in my data set. One of the elements that is repeated is a square avatar/profile image. I want to mask each of these images to make them rounded.

I thought that defining a mask in defs and then pointing each of the images at it would work, but it does not because their coordinates are different. Does this mean that I need to repeat the mask in each of the groups, like this:

```
<defs>
    <mask id="#mask" ...>
        <!-- ... --->
    </mask>
</defs>

<g>
    <rect ... />
    <use id="uniqueMask1" xlink:href="#mask" transform="translate(10, 10)" />
    <image x="10" y="10" ... mask="url(#uniqueMask1)" />
</g>

<!-- repeat multiple times -->
```

What I had hoped was to define the mask once, and then reference it from the `<image mask="..." />` attribute. This doesn't seem possible though. Is there another approach that could work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your mask using `maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"`.  In this mode, the coords you use are all relative to the object's bounding box.  So for example, a circular mask covering the object would be:

```
<mask maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <circle cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.5" fill="white">
</mask>
```

Comment: Great, this sounds like it will help a lot.